# UTF-8 conversion in Android?

Tags: java, android, string, utf-8

I am encountering a problem that I need to call a web service. I just need to generate a UTF-8 encoded url string. Because the parameter may contain spaces, I am using below piece of code to encode to utf-8:

```
public String encodeUTF(String str) {

        try {
            byte[] utf8Bytes = str.getBytes("UTF-8");

            String encodedStr = new String(utf8Bytes, "UTF-8");

            return encodedStr;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str;
    }
```

But still I am getting the same value. Because of this I am getting illegal argument exception while calling the service. Any ideas?

Comment: "UTF-8 encode for the URL because it may contain spaces"? Are you sure that's what you want to do? UTF-8 spaces are the same as ASCII spaces. Don't you want to *URL encode* it?

Comment: @deceze: yes. thats what i want to do it man.

Comment: @Praveen how did you solved the problem?

Answer (score 11):

For UTF encoding use this -> `URLEncoder.encode(string, "UTF-8");`

Also you need to change spaces -> `string.replace(" ", "%20");`

Answer (score 6):

Just try it:

```
URLEncoder.encode(str, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: now i am not getting illeagal argument exception. but i got http response exception: bad request . do you have any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this:

```
import java.net.URLEncoder;

class{
    String TEXT;

    TEXT= URLEncoder.encode(TEXT, "UTF-8");

}
```